# Blackberry invoke button Click Programmatically

Tags: blackberry

I want to invoke a button click event programmatically in blackberry. How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventInjector.NavigationEvent

```
EventInjector.invokeEvent(new EventInjector.NavigationEvent(EventInjector.Navig ationEvent.NAVIGATION_CLICK, 0, 0, 0));
```